# What are some early network file systems?

Tags: history, file-system, network

I know it's always hard to define an exact first, so I'll just ask about early network file systems.  To be more specific, I'm wondering about file systems that transparently present directories and files as if they were local.  I don't consider FTP or similar mechanisms to be candidates.

For some time it has been my suspicion that the ITS "MLDEV" facility was very early ("the first"), but I never had any facts to back it up.  I do have a file timestamped November 1972 that gives us an upper bound for the introduction of the facility.  On the MIT-AI PDP-10, it provided an ML device (hence the name) which worked much like the local DSK device except the data was accessed through MIT's ARPANET IMP.  MIT-ML of course had an AI device.

Comment: How do you define "transparently ... as if they were local"?

Comment: What do the acronyms "ML" and "AI" stand for?

Comment: So simply adding one or more levels to a hierarchy in a file name is OK? e.g., if a local file is specified as `[DISK]<DIRECTORY>FILE`, it's 'transparent' if I specify a remote file as `{COMPUTER}[DISK]<DIRECTORY>FILE`, but converting `C:\FOO\BAR\BAZ` to `\\REMOTE\C$\FOO\BAR\BAZ` is _not_ transparent?

Comment: I don't think it was first, but DECnet had "remote file access" but not always integrated into the kernel file access calls.  On RSX-11M for example, there were user-mode libraries that provided remote and local access transparently, but a program that was using the "native" calls would not automatically have remote access.  My point: does this sort of thing qualify for "transparent" access?

Comment: Acorn had their "Econet" network in the early 80's . Sinclair had (sort of, ''twas a very good idea but slightly badly implemented imo with far too much near essential functionality missing) the "ZXNet" with the Interface1 adding this ability for the Spectrum and the network hardware was iirc actually built into the QL as standard. I cannot comment further on other similar home/consumer machines as I am not familiar enough with other marques. I'm assuming 8 and 16 but systems are part of your question :)

Comment: I'm hoping this doesn't evolve into a discussion about the exact definitions (which will never settle) of what constitutes network or transparency.  I'd rather people decide for themselves and describe the technology.

Comment: @snips-n-snails, AI means artificial intelligence, specifically MIT's AI lab, and ML means mathlab.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff In order for a question to be answerable, you need it to be exact or it WILL end in discussions.  Instead of using some generic term then ask for the precise behavior you are thinking of.

Comment: Investigate The Cambridge Ring, the Cambridge File Server and WFS at Xerox PARC.

Comment: @AlanB, thank you.  As far as I can see, a network was installed in the mid 1970s, and remote file access came around 1980.

Comment: There was JANet (Joint Academic Network) in the 1960s.  It linked most UK universities and sort of still exists as a subnet of the Internet.  However, this is a list question.

Comment: @Chenmunka JANet is a network. Whether a particular computer could treat a file on another computer as if it was a local file is the question. Theoretically, it would have been possible in the 60's. In practice, there were probably no implementations.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "Transparent" in this context means any program that is capable of manipulating local files is also capable of manipulating remote files without modification. For example, if you have a "copy" command then either the source or the destination or both may be specified as a remote file location.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused about the definition of a filing system here. For the sake of argument, would a C1541 satisfy the criteria? It's a complete computer of its own that sits on a serial network with up to seven other computers and responds server/client fashion to incoming file requests to whomever may ask. But the filing system has no multiuser or concurrency features, and the machines making the requests contain none of the filing system.

Comment: @Tommy It may not be what I had in mind, but I'd rather keep the criteria loose to learn about these things.  Thanks!

Comment: Certainly not the first but I am surprised nobody has mentioned CP/NET (1980) which gave you remote drive letters under CP/M that worked exactly like local ones (or pretty close) and were shareable between multiple clients and the file server (running MP/M). It's really a syscall RPC interface but because drives are clearly separate in the file tree that is sufficient to do the job well. It was one of the first widely deployed network file systems as we think of them today.  Interestingly 'fileserver' was one a trademark of Keybrook.

Comment: Thank you @AlanCox, that's a very good example.  I didn't know about this, but come to think of it I may actually have used it in school as a kid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Present evidence is that ITS had a very early networked file system no later than 1972.

---

ITS has had a facility called the "ML Device", or MLDEV, for a long time.  The name probably comes from a time when the users of the older more established computer called AI wanted access to files on the computer called ML.  The "device" part is because ITS files are named by four parts: device, directory, and two file names.  To access ML files from AI, the device name is ML.  Conversely, from ML the AI device is used.

To date this facility, we can check timestamps from backup tapes.  The earliest file called MLDEV is from July 1975.  However, if we examine the source code for an earlier ITS version we see that it has built in ML and AI devices that when accessed starts a program called SYS; ATSIGN OTHER.  Disassembling this file we can see that it indeed is accepting file operations and sends information across ARPANET.  The earliest file with that name has a timestamp from November 1972.

We know from RFC documents 342, 344, and 366 that AI and ML were first put on the ARPANET in May-June 1972.  So MLDEV could not have been in use before 1972.